# Coding Practice: Why do do the iterators need to be aliased?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I've completed a question from algo expert that asks you to loop through an array of numbers to find the two numbers that add to a target sum.  I'm trying to understand why this function does not work without the iterators being aliased.

input: `[3, 5, -4, 8, 11, 1, -1, 6], 10`
output: `[-1, 11]`

This is the correct solution:

```py
def twoNumberSum(array, targetSum):
    for i in range(len(array) - 1):
        firstNum = array[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
            secondNum = array[j]
            if firstNum + secondNum == targetSum:
                return [firstNum, secondNum]
    return []
```

and I don't understand why this does not work:

```py
def twoNumberSum(array, targetSum):
    for i in range(len(array) - 1):

        for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):

            if i + j == targetSum:
                return [i, j]
    return []
```

Comment: `i` and `j` aren't the values of the arrays... they're just the positions...

Comment: This is not *"aliasing"*... This is list subscript which means accessing the list in the given index. You loop through indices and want to retrieve the actual **element** by doing `array[index]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, i and j are no values but your index.

It is always good to just test the output with a small example.

when

```
a=[6,7,8,9,10]
```

try to see what the range is over the length of a

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(i)
```

this will result in

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

and not

```
6
7
8
9
10
```

I hope that made it clearer.
Keep healthy.